# How to get specific landmark of face like lips or eyes using tensorflow.js face-landmark-detection model

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, computer-vision, tensorflow.js

I am trying to change the shape and position of eyes and lips and for this purpose I use tenserflow.js [face-landmark-detection model](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/face-landmarks-detection). I get the all 468 facial landmarks but the problem is i don't know and i never find any solution on internet how to get the position of only required landmark like lips and eyes. I get all the points but want to apply changes on lips and eyes how i apply changes only on these landmarks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The coordinates of are available [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/blob/master/face-landmarks-detection/src/mediapipe-facemesh/keypoints.ts).

You can refer to the [mesh image example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/face-landmarks-detection#keypoints) which has the points as well but you would need to zoom in and check them manually.

These are the exact coordinates that you would need for your use case.

```
lipsUpperOuter: [61, 185, 40, 39, 37, 0, 267, 269, 270, 409, 291]
lipsLowerOuter: [146, 91, 181, 84, 17, 314, 405, 321, 375, 291]
lipsUpperInner: [78, 191, 80, 81, 82, 13, 312, 311, 310, 415, 308]
lipsLowerInner: [78, 95, 88, 178, 87, 14, 317, 402, 318, 324, 308]
rightEyeUpper0: [246, 161, 160, 159, 158, 157, 173]
rightEyeLower0: [33, 7, 163, 144, 145, 153, 154, 155, 133]
rightEyeUpper1: [247, 30, 29, 27, 28, 56, 190]
rightEyeLower1: [130, 25, 110, 24, 23, 22, 26, 112, 243]
rightEyeUpper2: [113, 225, 224, 223, 222, 221, 189]
rightEyeLower2: [226, 31, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 244]
rightEyeLower3: [143, 111, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 128, 245]
rightEyebrowUpper: [156, 70, 63, 105, 66, 107, 55, 193]
rightEyebrowLower: [35, 124, 46, 53, 52, 65]
rightEyeIris: [473, 474, 475, 476, 477]
leftEyeUpper0: [466, 388, 387, 386, 385, 384, 398]
leftEyeLower0: [263, 249, 390, 373, 374, 380, 381, 382, 362]
leftEyeUpper1: [467, 260, 259, 257, 258, 286, 414]
leftEyeLower1: [359, 255, 339, 254, 253, 252, 256, 341, 463]
leftEyeUpper2: [342, 445, 444, 443, 442, 441, 413]
leftEyeLower2: [446, 261, 448, 449, 450, 451, 452, 453, 464]
leftEyeLower3: [372, 340, 346, 347, 348, 349, 350, 357, 465]
leftEyebrowUpper: [383, 300, 293, 334, 296, 336, 285, 417]
leftEyebrowLower: [265, 353, 276, 283, 282, 295]
leftEyeIris: [468, 469, 470, 471, 472]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help now it's clear for me how to use these points to make changes .

Answer (score 0):

Using `cv2` lib I assigned each point of a stock image to its designated point, so as to have a graph of whatever points I may need, it might be helpful to others so posting it here

```py
faces = det.findFaceMesh(img)

for id in range(10,400):
    (x,y) = face[id]
    conv = str(id)
    cv2.putText(img, (conv), (x,y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,1.25,(255,0,0))
```

above code for anyone who wants to change the range.
[All the Graph nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaFKg.jpg)