# How to create a path drawing algorithm to display specific landmarks of a face mesh in Landmark Detection with Tensorflow.JS and React?

Tags: reactjs, data-structures, geometry, tensorflow.js, mediapipe

I have currently implemented a version of this tutorial:

[Real Time AI Face Landmark Detection in 20 Minutes with Tensorflow.JS and React](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7lXYGDVHUNw)

It demonstrates how to implement the Tensorflow.JS facemesh model, and how to display the mesh using a drawPath function.

The code works as follows:

```
function App() {
  const webcamRef = useRef(null);
  const canvasRef = useRef(null);

  //  Load posenet

  const runFacemesh = async () => {
    const net = await facemesh.load(facemesh.SupportedPackages.mediapipeFacemesh);
    setInterval(() => {
      detect(net);
    }, 10);
  };

  const detect = async (net) => {
    // check a return on webcam data 
    if (
      typeof webcamRef.current !== "undefined" &&
      webcamRef.current !== null &&
      webcamRef.current.video.readyState === 4
    ) {
      // Get Video Properties
      const video = webcamRef.current.video;
      const videoWidth = webcamRef.current.video.videoWidth;
      const videoHeight = webcamRef.current.video.videoHeight;

      // Set video width
      webcamRef.current.video.width = videoWidth;
      webcamRef.current.video.height = videoHeight;

      // Set canvas width and height
      canvasRef.current.width = videoWidth;
      canvasRef.current.height = videoHeight;

      // feed vid
      const face = await net.estimateFaces({input:video});
      // console.log(face);

      // Get canvas context
      const yY = canvasRef.current.getContext("2d");
      requestAnimationFrame(()=>{drawMesh(face, ctx)});
    }
  };

  // call function for drawing facemesh
  useEffect(()=>{runFacemesh()}, []);

  // setup webcam and canvas
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <Webcam
          ref={webcamRef}
          style={{
            position: "absolute",
            marginLeft: "auto",
            marginRight: "auto",
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            textAlign: "center",
            zindex: 9,
            width: 640,
            height: 480,
          }}
        />

        <canvas
          ref={canvasRef}
          style={{
            position: "absolute",
            marginLeft: "auto",
            marginRight: "auto",
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            textAlign: "center",
            zindex: 9,
            width: 640,
            height: 480,
          }}
        />
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Above is the main app function that loads the facemesh and detects the model. Within this function I am calling a drawMesh function which takes a face parameter which is defined as the estimated detections called against the video input and a ctx object:

The drawMesh function and path drawing method are defined as follows:

```
// Triangle drawing method
const drawPath = (ctx, points, closePath) => {
  const region = new Path2D();
  region.moveTo(points[0][0], points[0][1]);
  for (let i = 1; i < points.length; i++) {
    const point = points[i];
    region.lineTo(point[0], point[1]);
  }

  if (closePath) {
    region.closePath();
  }
  ctx.strokeStyle = "grey";
  ctx.stroke(region);
};

// Drawing Mesh
export const drawMesh = (predictions, ctx) => {
  if (predictions.length > 0) {
    predictions.forEach((prediction) => {
      const keypoints = prediction.scaledMesh;

      //  Draw Triangles
      for (let i = 0; i < TRIANGULATION.length / 3; i++) {
        // Get sets of three keypoints for the triangle
        const points = [
          TRIANGULATION[i * 3],
          TRIANGULATION[i * 3 + 1],
          TRIANGULATION[i * 3 + 2],
        ].map((index) => keypoints[index]);
        //  Draw triangle
        drawPath(ctx, points, true);
      }

      // Draw Dots
      for (let i = 0; i < keypoints.length; i++) {
        const x = keypoints[i][0];
        const y = keypoints[i][1];

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x, y, 1 /* radius */, 0, 3 * Math.PI);
        ctx.fillStyle = "aqua";
        ctx.fill();
      }
    });
  }
};
```

It works by referring points from a triangle array defined here:

```
export const TRIANGULATION = [
  127, 34, 139, 11, 0, 37, 232, 231, 120, 72, 37, 39, 128, 121, 47, 232, 121,
  128, 104, 69, 67, 175, 171, 148, 157, 154, 155, 118, 50, 101, 73, 39, 40, 9,
  151, 108, 48, 115, 131, 194, 204, 211, 74, 40, 185, 80, 42, 183, 40, 92, 186,
  230, 229, 118, 202, 212, 214, 83, 18, 17, 76, 61, 146, 160, 29, 30, 56, 157,
  173, 106, 204, 194, 135, 214, 192, 203, 165, 98, 21, 71, 68, 51, 45, 4, 144,
  24, 23, 77, 146, 91, 205, 50, 187, 201, 200, 18, 91, 106, 182, 90, 91, 181,
  85, 84, 17, 206, 203, 36, 148, 171, 140, 92, 40, 39, 193, 189, 244, 159, 158,
  28, 247, 246, 161, 236, 3, 196, 54, 68, 104, 193, 168, 8, 117, 228, 31, 189,
  193, 55, 98, 97, 99, 126, 47, 100, 166, 79, 218, 155, 154, 26, 209, 49, 131,
  135, 136, 150, 47, 126, 217, 223, 52, 53, 45, 51, 134, 211, 170, 140, 67, 69,
  108, 43, 106, 91, 230, 119, 120, 226, 130, 247, 63, 53, 52, 238, 20, 242, 46,
  70, 156, 78, 62, 96, 46, 53, 63, 143, 34, 227, 173, 155, 133, 123, 117, 111,
  44, 125, 19, 236, 134, 51, 216, 206, 205, 154, 153, 22, 39, 37, 167, 200, 201,
  208, 36, 142, 100, 57, 212, 202, 20, 60, 99, 28, 158, 157, 35, 226, 113, 160,
  159, 27, 204, 202, 210, 113, 225, 46, 43, 202, 204, 62, 76, 77, 137, 123, 116,
  41, 38, 72, 203, 129, 142, 64, 98, 240, 49, 102, 64, 41, 73, 74, 212, 216,
  207, 42, 74, 184, 169, 170, 211, 170, 149, 176, 105, 66, 69, 122, 6, 168, 123,
  147, 187, 96, 77, 90, 65, 55, 107, 89, 90, 180, 101, 100, 120, 63, 105, 104,
  93, 137, 227, 15, 86, 85, 129, 102, 49, 14, 87, 86, 55, 8, 9, 100, 47, 121,
  145, 23, 22, 88, 89, 179, 6, 122, 196, 88, 95, 96, 138, 172, 136, 215, 58,
  172, 115, 48, 219, 42, 80, 81, 195, 3, 51, 43, 146, 61, 171, 175, 199, 81, 82,
  38, 53, 46, 225, 144, 163, 110, 246, 33, 7, 52, 65, 66, 229, 228, 117, 34,
  127, 234, 107, 108, 69, 109, 108, 151, 48, 64, 235, 62, 78, 191, 129, 209,
  126, 111, 35, 143, 163, 161, 246, 117, 123, 50, 222, 65, 52, 19, 125, 141,
  221, 55, 65, 3, 195, 197, 25, 7, 33, 220, 237, 44, 70, 71, 139, 122, 193, 245,
  247, 130, 33, 71, 21, 162, 153, 158, 159, 170, 169, 150, 188, 174, 196, 216,
  186, 92, 144, 160, 161, 2, 97, 167, 141, 125, 241, 164, 167, 37, 72, 38, 12,
  145, 159, 160, 38, 82, 13, 63, 68, 71, 226, 35, 111, 158, 153, 154, 101, 50,
  205, 206, 92, 165, 209, 198, 217, 165, 167, 97, 220, 115, 218, 133, 112, 243,
  239, 238, 241, 214, 135, 169, 190, 173, 133, 171, 208, 32, 125, 44, 237, 86,
  87, 178, 85, 86, 179, 84, 85, 180, 83, 84, 181, 201, 83, 182, 137, 93, 132,
  76, 62, 183, 61, 76, 184, 57, 61, 185, 212, 57, 186, 214, 207, 187, 34, 143,
  156, 79, 239, 237, 123, 137, 177, 44, 1, 4, 201, 194, 32, 64, 102, 129, 213,
  215, 138, 59, 166, 219, 242, 99, 97, 2, 94, 141, 75, 59, 235, 24, 110, 228,
  25, 130, 226, 23, 24, 229, 22, 23, 230, 26, 22, 231, 112, 26, 232, 189, 190,
  243, 221, 56, 190, 28, 56, 221, 27, 28, 222, 29, 27, 223, 30, 29, 224, 247,
  30, 225, 238, 79, 20, 166, 59, 75, 60, 75, 240, 147, 177, 215, 20, 79, 166,
  187, 147, 213, 112, 233, 244, 233, 128, 245, 128, 114, 188, 114, 217, 174,
  131, 115, 220, 217, 198, 236, 198, 131, 134, 177, 132, 58, 143, 35, 124, 110,
  163, 7, 228, 110, 25, 356, 389, 368, 11, 302, 267, 452, 350, 349, 302, 303,
  269, 357, 343, 277, 452, 453, 357, 333, 332, 297, 175, 152, 377, 384, 398,
  382, 347, 348, 330, 303, 304, 270, 9, 336, 337, 278, 279, 360, 418, 262, 431,
  304, 408, 409, 310, 415, 407, 270, 409, 410, 450, 348, 347, 422, 430, 434,
  313, 314, 17, 306, 307, 375, 387, 388, 260, 286, 414, 398, 335, 406, 418, 364,
  367, 416, 423, 358, 327, 251, 284, 298, 281, 5, 4, 373, 374, 253, 307, 320,
  321, 425, 427, 411, 421, 313, 18, 321, 405, 406, 320, 404, 405, 315, 16, 17,
  426, 425, 266, 377, 400, 369, 322, 391, 269, 417, 465, 464, 386, 257, 258,
  466, 260, 388, 456, 399, 419, 284, 332, 333, 417, 285, 8, 346, 340, 261, 413,
  441, 285, 327, 460, 328, 355, 371, 329, 392, 439, 438, 382, 341, 256, 429,
  420, 360, 364, 394, 379, 277, 343, 437, 443, 444, 283, 275, 440, 363, 431,
  262, 369, 297, 338, 337, 273, 375, 321, 450, 451, 349, 446, 342, 467, 293,
  334, 282, 458, 461, 462, 276, 353, 383, 308, 324, 325, 276, 300, 293, 372,
  345, 447, 382, 398, 362, 352, 345, 340, 274, 1, 19, 456, 248, 281, 436, 427,
  425, 381, 256, 252, 269, 391, 393, 200, 199, 428, 266, 330, 329, 287, 273,
  422, 250, 462, 328, 258, 286, 384, 265, 353, 342, 387, 259, 257, 424, 431,
  430, 342, 353, 276, 273, 335, 424, 292, 325, 307, 366, 447, 345, 271, 303,
  302, 423, 266, 371, 294, 455, 460, 279, 278, 294, 271, 272, 304, 432, 434,
  427, 272, 407, 408, 394, 430, 431, 395, 369, 400, 334, 333, 299, 351, 417,
  168, 352, 280, 411, 325, 319, 320, 295, 296, 336, 319, 403, 404, 330, 348,
  349, 293, 298, 333, 323, 454, 447, 15, 16, 315, 358, 429, 279, 14, 15, 316,
  285, 336, 9, 329, 349, 350, 374, 380, 252, 318, 402, 403, 6, 197, 419, 318,
  319, 325, 367, 364, 365, 435, 367, 397, 344, 438, 439, 272, 271, 311, 195, 5,
  281, 273, 287, 291, 396, 428, 199, 311, 271, 268, 283, 444, 445, 373, 254,
  339, 263, 466, 249, 282, 334, 296, 449, 347, 346, 264, 447, 454, 336, 296,
  299, 338, 10, 151, 278, 439, 455, 292, 407, 415, 358, 371, 355, 340, 345, 372,
  390, 249, 466, 346, 347, 280, 442, 443, 282, 19, 94, 370, 441, 442, 295, 248,
  419, 197, 263, 255, 359, 440, 275, 274, 300, 383, 368, 351, 412, 465, 263,
  467, 466, 301, 368, 389, 380, 374, 386, 395, 378, 379, 412, 351, 419, 436,
  426, 322, 373, 390, 388, 2, 164, 393, 370, 462, 461, 164, 0, 267, 302, 11, 12,
  374, 373, 387, 268, 12, 13, 293, 300, 301, 446, 261, 340, 385, 384, 381, 330,
  266, 425, 426, 423, 391, 429, 355, 437, 391, 327, 326, 440, 457, 438, 341,
  382, 362, 459, 457, 461, 434, 430, 394, 414, 463, 362, 396, 369, 262, 354,
  461, 457, 316, 403, 402, 315, 404, 403, 314, 405, 404, 313, 406, 405, 421,
  418, 406, 366, 401, 361, 306, 408, 407, 291, 409, 408, 287, 410, 409, 432,
  436, 410, 434, 416, 411, 264, 368, 383, 309, 438, 457, 352, 376, 401, 274,
  275, 4, 421, 428, 262, 294, 327, 358, 433, 416, 367, 289, 455, 439, 462, 370,
  326, 2, 326, 370, 305, 460, 455, 254, 449, 448, 255, 261, 446, 253, 450, 449,
  252, 451, 450, 256, 452, 451, 341, 453, 452, 413, 464, 463, 441, 413, 414,
  258, 442, 441, 257, 443, 442, 259, 444, 443, 260, 445, 444, 467, 342, 445,
  459, 458, 250, 289, 392, 290, 290, 328, 460, 376, 433, 435, 250, 290, 392,
  411, 416, 433, 341, 463, 464, 453, 464, 465, 357, 465, 412, 343, 412, 399,
  360, 363, 440, 437, 399, 456, 420, 456, 363, 401, 435, 288, 372, 383, 353,
  339, 255, 249, 448, 261, 255, 133, 243, 190, 133, 155, 112, 33, 246, 247, 33,
  130, 25, 398, 384, 286, 362, 398, 414, 362, 463, 341, 263, 359, 467, 263, 249,
  255, 466, 467, 260, 75, 60, 166, 238, 239, 79, 162, 127, 139, 72, 11, 37, 121,
  232, 120, 73, 72, 39, 114, 128, 47, 233, 232, 128, 103, 104, 67, 152, 175,
  148, 173, 157, 155, 119, 118, 101, 74, 73, 40, 107, 9, 108, 49, 48, 131, 32,
  194, 211, 184, 74, 185, 191, 80, 183, 185, 40, 186, 119, 230, 118, 210, 202,
  214, 84, 83, 17, 77, 76, 146, 161, 160, 30, 190, 56, 173, 182, 106, 194, 138,
  135, 192, 129, 203, 98, 54, 21, 68, 5, 51, 4, 145, 144, 23, 90, 77, 91, 207,
  205, 187, 83, 201, 18, 181, 91, 182, 180, 90, 181, 16, 85, 17, 205, 206, 36,
  176, 148, 140, 165, 92, 39, 245, 193, 244, 27, 159, 28, 30, 247, 161, 174,
  236, 196, 103, 54, 104, 55, 193, 8, 111, 117, 31, 221, 189, 55, 240, 98, 99,
  142, 126, 100, 219, 166, 218, 112, 155, 26, 198, 209, 131, 169, 135, 150, 114,
  47, 217, 224, 223, 53, 220, 45, 134, 32, 211, 140, 109, 67, 108, 146, 43, 91,
  231, 230, 120, 113, 226, 247, 105, 63, 52, 241, 238, 242, 124, 46, 156, 95,
  78, 96, 70, 46, 63, 116, 143, 227, 116, 123, 111, 1, 44, 19, 3, 236, 51, 207,
  216, 205, 26, 154, 22, 165, 39, 167, 199, 200, 208, 101, 36, 100, 43, 57, 202,
  242, 20, 99, 56, 28, 157, 124, 35, 113, 29, 160, 27, 211, 204, 210, 124, 113,
  46, 106, 43, 204, 96, 62, 77, 227, 137, 116, 73, 41, 72, 36, 203, 142, 235,
  64, 240, 48, 49, 64, 42, 41, 74, 214, 212, 207, 183, 42, 184, 210, 169, 211,
  140, 170, 176, 104, 105, 69, 193, 122, 168, 50, 123, 187, 89, 96, 90, 66, 65,
  107, 179, 89, 180, 119, 101, 120, 68, 63, 104, 234, 93, 227, 16, 15, 85, 209,
  129, 49, 15, 14, 86, 107, 55, 9, 120, 100, 121, 153, 145, 22, 178, 88, 179,
  197, 6, 196, 89, 88, 96, 135, 138, 136, 138, 215, 172, 218, 115, 219, 41, 42,
  81, 5, 195, 51, 57, 43, 61, 208, 171, 199, 41, 81, 38, 224, 53, 225, 24, 144,
  110, 105, 52, 66, 118, 229, 117, 227, 34, 234, 66, 107, 69, 10, 109, 151, 219,
  48, 235, 183, 62, 191, 142, 129, 126, 116, 111, 143, 7, 163, 246, 118, 117,
  50, 223, 222, 52, 94, 19, 141, 222, 221, 65, 196, 3, 197, 45, 220, 44, 156,
  70, 139, 188, 122, 245, 139, 71, 162, 145, 153, 159, 149, 170, 150, 122, 188,
  196, 206, 216, 92, 163, 144, 161, 164, 2, 167, 242, 141, 241, 0, 164, 37, 11,
  72, 12, 144, 145, 160, 12, 38, 13, 70, 63, 71, 31, 226, 111, 157, 158, 154,
  36, 101, 205, 203, 206, 165, 126, 209, 217, 98, 165, 97, 237, 220, 218, 237,
  239, 241, 210, 214, 169, 140, 171, 32, 241, 125, 237, 179, 86, 178, 180, 85,
  179, 181, 84, 180, 182, 83, 181, 194, 201, 182, 177, 137, 132, 184, 76, 183,
  185, 61, 184, 186, 57, 185, 216, 212, 186, 192, 214, 187, 139, 34, 156, 218,
  79, 237, 147, 123, 177, 45, 44, 4, 208, 201, 32, 98, 64, 129, 192, 213, 138,
  235, 59, 219, 141, 242, 97, 97, 2, 141, 240, 75, 235, 229, 24, 228, 31, 25,
  226, 230, 23, 229, 231, 22, 230, 232, 26, 231, 233, 112, 232, 244, 189, 243,
  189, 221, 190, 222, 28, 221, 223, 27, 222, 224, 29, 223, 225, 30, 224, 113,
  247, 225, 99, 60, 240, 213, 147, 215, 60, 20, 166, 192, 187, 213, 243, 112,
  244, 244, 233, 245, 245, 128, 188, 188, 114, 174, 134, 131, 220, 174, 217,
  236, 236, 198, 134, 215, 177, 58, 156, 143, 124, 25, 110, 7, 31, 228, 25, 264,
  356, 368, 0, 11, 267, 451, 452, 349, 267, 302, 269, 350, 357, 277, 350, 452,
  357, 299, 333, 297, 396, 175, 377, 381, 384, 382, 280, 347, 330, 269, 303,
  270, 151, 9, 337, 344, 278, 360, 424, 418, 431, 270, 304, 409, 272, 310, 407,
  322, 270, 410, 449, 450, 347, 432, 422, 434, 18, 313, 17, 291, 306, 375, 259,
  387, 260, 424, 335, 418, 434, 364, 416, 391, 423, 327, 301, 251, 298, 275,
  281, 4, 254, 373, 253, 375, 307, 321, 280, 425, 411, 200, 421, 18, 335, 321,
  406, 321, 320, 405, 314, 315, 17, 423, 426, 266, 396, 377, 369, 270, 322, 269,
  413, 417, 464, 385, 386, 258, 248, 456, 419, 298, 284, 333, 168, 417, 8, 448,
  346, 261, 417, 413, 285, 326, 327, 328, 277, 355, 329, 309, 392, 438, 381,
  382, 256, 279, 429, 360, 365, 364, 379, 355, 277, 437, 282, 443, 283, 281,
  275, 363, 395, 431, 369, 299, 297, 337, 335, 273, 321, 348, 450, 349, 359,
  446, 467, 283, 293, 282, 250, 458, 462, 300, 276, 383, 292, 308, 325, 283,
  276, 293, 264, 372, 447, 346, 352, 340, 354, 274, 19, 363, 456, 281, 426, 436,
  425, 380, 381, 252, 267, 269, 393, 421, 200, 428, 371, 266, 329, 432, 287,
  422, 290, 250, 328, 385, 258, 384, 446, 265, 342, 386, 387, 257, 422, 424,
  430, 445, 342, 276, 422, 273, 424, 306, 292, 307, 352, 366, 345, 268, 271,
  302, 358, 423, 371, 327, 294, 460, 331, 279, 294, 303, 271, 304, 436, 432,
  427, 304, 272, 408, 395, 394, 431, 378, 395, 400, 296, 334, 299, 6, 351, 168,
  376, 352, 411, 307, 325, 320, 285, 295, 336, 320, 319, 404, 329, 330, 349,
  334, 293, 333, 366, 323, 447, 316, 15, 315, 331, 358, 279, 317, 14, 316, 8,
  285, 9, 277, 329, 350, 253, 374, 252, 319, 318, 403, 351, 6, 419, 324, 318,
  325, 397, 367, 365, 288, 435, 397, 278, 344, 439, 310, 272, 311, 248, 195,
  281, 375, 273, 291, 175, 396, 199, 312, 311, 268, 276, 283, 445, 390, 373,
  339, 295, 282, 296, 448, 449, 346, 356, 264, 454, 337, 336, 299, 337, 338,
  151, 294, 278, 455, 308, 292, 415, 429, 358, 355, 265, 340, 372, 388, 390,
  466, 352, 346, 280, 295, 442, 282, 354, 19, 370, 285, 441, 295, 195, 248, 197,
  457, 440, 274, 301, 300, 368, 417, 351, 465, 251, 301, 389, 385, 380, 386,
  394, 395, 379, 399, 412, 419, 410, 436, 322, 387, 373, 388, 326, 2, 393, 354,
  370, 461, 393, 164, 267, 268, 302, 12, 386, 374, 387, 312, 268, 13, 298, 293,
  301, 265, 446, 340, 380, 385, 381, 280, 330, 425, 322, 426, 391, 420, 429,
  437, 393, 391, 326, 344, 440, 438, 458, 459, 461, 364, 434, 394, 428, 396,
  262, 274, 354, 457, 317, 316, 402, 316, 315, 403, 315, 314, 404, 314, 313,
  405, 313, 421, 406, 323, 366, 361, 292, 306, 407, 306, 291, 408, 291, 287,
  409, 287, 432, 410, 427, 434, 411, 372, 264, 383, 459, 309, 457, 366, 352,
  401, 1, 274, 4, 418, 421, 262, 331, 294, 358, 435, 433, 367, 392, 289, 439,
  328, 462, 326, 94, 2, 370, 289, 305, 455, 339, 254, 448, 359, 255, 446, 254,
  253, 449, 253, 252, 450, 252, 256, 451, 256, 341, 452, 414, 413, 463, 286,
  441, 414, 286, 258, 441, 258, 257, 442, 257, 259, 443, 259, 260, 444, 260,
  467, 445, 309, 459, 250, 305, 289, 290, 305, 290, 460, 401, 376, 435, 309,
  250, 392, 376, 411, 433, 453, 341, 464, 357, 453, 465, 343, 357, 412, 437,
  343, 399, 344, 360, 440, 420, 437, 456, 360, 420, 363, 361, 401, 288, 265,
  372, 353, 390, 339, 249, 339, 448, 255,
];
```

My understanding is that it takes Array[[x1,y1,z1],[x2,y2,z2],[x3,y3,z3]], each time a new set of three comes down from the matrix with the starting position being reset each time to ensure clear triangular structures.

What I would like to do is employ some different algorithms to render the facial landmarks.
There are different arrays available here:

[How to get specific landmark of face like lips or eyes using tensorflow.js face-landmark-detection model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66649492/how-to-get-specific-landmark-of-face-like-lips-or-eyes-using-tensorflow-js-face)

My issue is that I do not know how to manipulate the draw mesh function so that it draws liner patterns.

My attempts at integrating one of the landmarks for lips uses the array:

```
export const lipsUpperOuter = [61, 185, 40, 39, 37, 0, 267, 269, 270, 409, 291];

  for (let i = 0; i < lipsUpperOuter.length; i++) {
    const points = [lipsUpperOuter[i]].map((index) => keypoints[index]);

    drawPath(ctx, points, true);
  }
```

However this renders nothing?

My ultimate goal is to be able to define my own points A to B to C etc.. to make more artist representations of the mesh?

Does anyone know how I should adjust the method to achieve this?

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I'm working on a similar project.